# Access Prometheus GUI on Kubernetes Cluster with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, prometheus-operator

I have installed Istio on my GKE cluster using Istio CLI. I have read that Prometheus comes default with Istio.

How do I confirm if Prometheus is correctly installed and how do I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# kubectl get po -n istio-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-egressgateway-64d976b9b5-pmf8d    1/1     Running   0          18d
istio-ingressgateway-68c86b9fc8-94ftm   1/1     Running   0          18d
istiod-5c986fb85b-h6v4r                 1/1     Running   0          18d
prometheus-7bfddb8dbf-x2p2x             2/2     Running   0          18d
zipkin-7fcd647cf9-hp8qs                 1/1     Running   0          18d
```

If it's not there, deploy it with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.9/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Worked great!